# Python Pandas: Is Order Preserved When Using groupby() and agg()?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I've frequented used pandas' `agg()` function to run summary statistics on every column of a data.frame.  For example, here's how you would produce the mean and standard deviation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['group1', 'group1', 'group2', 'group2', 'group3', 'group3'],
                   'B': [10, 12, 10, 25, 10, 12],
                   'C': [100, 102, 100, 250, 100, 102]})

>>> df
[output]
        A   B    C
0  group1  10  100
1  group1  12  102
2  group2  10  100
3  group2  25  250
4  group3  10  100
5  group3  12  102
```

In both of those cases, the order that individual rows are sent to the agg function does not matter.  But consider the following example, which:

```
df.groupby('A').agg([np.mean, lambda x: x.iloc[1] ])

[output]

        mean  <lambda>  mean  <lambda>
A                                     
group1  11.0        12   101       102
group2  17.5        25   175       250
group3  11.0        12   101       102
```

In this case the lambda functions as intended, outputting the second row in each group.  However, I have not been able to find anything in the pandas documentation that implies that this is guaranteed to be true in all cases.  I want use `agg()` along with a weighted average function, so I want to be sure that the rows that come into the function will be in the same order as they appear in the original data frame.

Does anyone know, ideally via somewhere in the docs or pandas source code, if this is guaranteed to be the case?

Comment: Yes, I can't see any guarantees that order is preserved in the docs, so it does seem a bit unwise to rely on it. If the ordering is reflected by your `B` column then you could sort each group by `B` within the lambda to make sure.

Comment: Unfortunately I want to keep the rows ordered by a column that isn't included in the aggregation.  The data frame is sorted before the `agg()` call, so it's only a problem if it reorders it as part of the `groupby()`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

See this enhancement [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8588)

The short answer is yes, the groupby will preserve the orderings as passed in. You can prove this by using your example like this:

```
In [20]: df.sort_index(ascending=False).groupby('A').agg([np.mean, lambda x: x.iloc[1] ])
Out[20]: 
           B             C         
        mean <lambda> mean <lambda>
A                                  
group1  11.0       10  101      100
group2  17.5       10  175      100
group3  11.0       10  101      100
```

This is NOT true for resample however as it requires a monotonic index (it WILL work with a non-monotonic index, but will sort it first).

Their is a `sort=` flag to groupby, but this relates to the sorting of the groups themselves and not the observations within a group.

FYI: `df.groupby('A').nth(1)` is a safe way to get the 2nd value of a group (as your method above will fail if a group has < 2 elements)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the issue link!  I originally used `iloc` as an example because I couldn't figure out how to pass in `nth()` to the `agg()` call (because at that point `x` is a series).  Is there some way to call `nth()` other than as a DataFrame member function?

Comment: ``nth`` is only defined on a groupby. What do you mean 'other than a DataFrame member function'?

Comment: I meant I couldn't figure out how to pass `nth()` as one of the functions sent in the list to `agg()`.  You can't do `.agg([np.mean, nth])`, or `DataFrame.nth()` or `lambda x: x.nth(2)`.  That's what led my to iloc, though it will throw index errors.  The best way is probably to not try to do it all in one step; first use `nth()` then use `agg()`, then merge them.

Answer (score 52):

In order to preserve order, you'll need to pass `.groupby(..., sort=False)`. In your case the grouping column is already sorted, so it does not make difference, but generally one must use the `sort=False` flag:

```
 df.groupby('A', sort=False).agg([np.mean, lambda x: x.iloc[1] ])
```

Comment: There is a sort= flag to groupby, but this relates to the sorting of the groups themselves and not the observations within a group.

Comment: they shoul've made this a default param, considering very often this gets used

Comment: It is ironic that the documentation says also "Get better performance by turning this off.". Well one more reason why it should have been an optional feature, not a default. Most importantly it makes changes to data that the caller might not expect.

Comment: as of pandas version 1.5.3, `sort` has default True. which was the opposite of my expectation.

Answer (score 30):

Panda's 0.19.1 doc says "groupby preserves the order of rows within each group", so this is guaranteed behavior.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 5):

Reference: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

The API accepts "SORT" as an argument.

Description for SORT argument is like this:

sort : bool, default True
Sort group keys. Get better performance by turning this off. Note this does not influence the order of observations within each group. **Groupby preserves the order of rows within each group**.

Thus, it is clear the "Groupby" does preserve the order of rows within each group.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the answer to this question is NO. In the past few days I've created an algorithm for non-uniform chunking and found that is cannot possibly retain order because a groupby introduces subframes where the key to each frame is the groupby input. So you end up with:

```
allSubFrames = df.groupby("myColumnToOrderBy")
for orderKey, individualSubFrame in allSubFrames:
     do something...
```

Because its using dictionaries you lose the ordering.

If you perform a sort afterwards, as mentioned above, which I've just tested for a massive dataset, you end up with an O(n log n) computation.

However, I found that if you have for instance ordered time series data in order, where you want to preserve the order, it is better to change the ordering column into a list and then create a counter that records the first item in each time series. This results in a O(n) calculation.

So, essentially if you are using a relatively small dataset the proposed answers above are reasonable, but if using a big data set you need to consider avoiding groupby and sort. Instead use: `list(df['myColumnToOrderBy'])` and iterator over it.

Comment: Can you, please, add a simple working code example to your answer?

Comment: No, I can't because you need a massive dataset, and it took me a long time to sort this issue out and am no longer working on that project.

Answer (score -1):

Even easier:

```
  import pandas as pd
  pd.pivot_table(df,index='A',aggfunc=(np.mean))
```

output:

```
            B    C
     A                
   group1  11.0  101
   group2  17.5  175
   group3  11.0  101
```