# Select latest in each group in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How to group values of pandas dataframe and select the latest (by date) from each group?

For example, given a dataframe sorted by date:

```
    id     product   date
0   220    6647     2014-09-01 
1   220    6647     2014-09-03 
2   220    6647     2014-10-16
3   826    3380     2014-11-11
4   826    3380     2014-12-09
5   826    3380     2015-05-19
6   901    4555     2014-09-01
7   901    4555     2014-10-05
8   901    4555     2014-11-01
```

grouping by id or product, and selecting the latest gives:

```
    id     product   date
2   220    6647     2014-10-16
5   826    3380     2015-05-19
8   901    4555     2014-11-01
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

use `idxmax` in `groupby` and slice `df` with `loc`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id').date.idxmax()]

    id  product       date
2  220     6647 2014-10-16
5  826     3380 2015-05-19
8  901     4555 2014-11-01
```

Comment: the solution works very slow for millions of records

Comment: In 2021 I get this error: KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported.

Comment: Use reindex instead

Comment: will this not work if date column has `NaT`s?

Answer (score 166):

You can also use `tail` with groupby to get the last n values of the group:

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby('id').tail(1)

    id  product date
2   220 6647    2014-10-16
8   901 4555    2014-11-01
5   826 3380    2015-05-19
```

Comment: I like this because it can be applied to more than just dates.

Comment: This option is significantly faster, than the accepted answer, but is less readable.
Also isn't it a problematic, that there is an assumption that `groupby` preserves order?

Comment: groupby preserves order, see 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456125/python-pandas-is-order-preserved-when-using-groupby-and-agg

Comment: @ade1e how would the code change to perform a resample (say per month or year) and keep the last n values of the group, rather than summing/averaging?

Comment: For haters of groupby: `df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')`

Answer (score 38):

I had a similar problem and ended up using `drop_duplicates` rather than `groupby`.

It seems to run significatively faster on large datasets when compared with other methods suggested above.

```
df.sort_values(by="date").drop_duplicates(subset=["id"], keep="last")

    id  product        date
2  220     6647  2014-10-16
8  901     4555  2014-11-01
5  826     3380  2015-05-19
```

Comment: I typically use this as well, but wish the faster solution was with the groupby. The groupby intuitively makes more sense and is usually how we think about solving this problem!

Comment: This approach, however, only works if you want to keep 1 record per group, rather than N records when using `tail` as per @nipy's answer

Answer (score 26):

Given a dataframe sorted by date, you can obtain what you ask for in a number of ways:

Like this:

```py
df.groupby(['id','product']).last()
```

like this:

```py
df.groupby(['id','product']).nth(-1)
```

or like this:

```py
df.groupby(['id','product']).max()
```

If you don't want `id` and `product` to appear as index use `groupby(['id', 'product'], as_index=False)`.
Alternatively use:

```py
df.groupby(['id','product']).tail(1)
```

Comment: In my tests, last() behaves a bit differently than nth(), when there are None values in the same column. For example, if first row in a group has the value 1 and the rest of the rows in the same group all have None, last() will return 1 as the value, although the last row has None. On the other hand nth(-1) will return None, which is more like what I expect.

Answer (score 4):

To use `.tail()` as an aggregation method and keep your grouping intact:

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.tail(1))

        id  product date
id              
220 2   220 6647    2014-10-16
826 5   826 3380    2015-05-19
901 8   901 4555    2014-11-01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import datetime library
from datetime import datetime as dt

#transform the date column to ordinal, or create a temp column converting to ordinal.
df['date'] = df.date.apply(lambda date: date.toordinal())

#apply aggregation function depending your desire. Earliest or Latest date.
latest_date = df.groupby('id').agg(latest=('date', max)) 
earliest_date = df.groupby('id').agg(earliest=('date', min)) 

#convert it from ordinal back to date.
df['date'] = df.date.apply(lambda date: dt.fromordinal(date))


#This operation may take seconds on millions of records.
```

Comment: Well, you certainly don't need to perform this conversion just to find the latest or earliest date.