# Filterning top n row based on groupby condition

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which have 4 column User_id,Transaction_id,product and datetime. For each user i have to select his top n recent transaction,Let assume n=2, My dataframe is like:

```
    transaction_id  user_id  product  date
         T1             U1     P1     2019-03-27
         T1             U1     P2     2019-03-27
         T1             U1     P3     2019-03-27
         T2             U1     P2     2019-03-21
         T2             U1     P3     2019-03-21
         T3             U1     P2     2019-03-20
```

I tried to do it by taking help of this [group by pandas dataframe and select latest in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525911/group-by-pandas-dataframe-and-select-latest-in-each-group)

What i am expecting as a output is:

```
   transaction_id   user_id  product  date
        T1            U1       P1     2019-03-27
        T1            U1       P2     2019-03-27
        T1            U1       P3     2019-03-27
        T2            U1       P2     2019-03-21
        T2            U1       P3     2019-03-21
```

Comment: Where is the question? What did you try so far?

Comment: df.sort_values('date',ascending = False).groupby(['order_id','user_id']).head(2) This is what i have tried but the problem with this code is it will give me top n transaction within one transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is remove duplicates first by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), get top2 values per groups and [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) original DataFrame:

```
df = (df.merge(df.drop_duplicates(['user_id','date'])
                 .sort_values('date',ascending = False)
                 .groupby('user_id')
                 .head(2)[['user_id','date']])
       )
print (df)
  transaction_id user_id product       date
0             T1      U1      P1 2019-03-27
1             T1      U1      P2 2019-03-27
2             T1      U1      P3 2019-03-27
3             T2      U1      P2 2019-03-21
4             T2      U1      P3 2019-03-21
```