# Python-dask/pandas How to delete/exclude the last observation in each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, dask

I am using Python `dask` to process a large csv panel data set (10GB+). 
The dataframe looks like

```
 stock     date     time   spread  time_diff 
  VOD      01-01    9:05    0.01     0:07     
  VOD      01-01    9:12    0.03     0:52     
  VOD      01-01   10:04    0.02     0:11
  VOD      01-01   10:15    0.01     0:10     
  VOD      01-01   10:25    0.03     0:36      
  VOD      01-01   11:01    0.02     0:03
  VOD      01-01   10:04    0.02     0:09  
  VOD      01-01   10:15    0.01     0:10   
  VOD      01-01   10:25    0.03     0:39  
  VOD      01-01   11:04    0.02    22:00 
  VOD      01-02    9:04    0.02     0:05
  ...       ...     ...     ....     ...
  BAT      01-01    13:05   0.04    10:02
  BAT      01-02    9:07    0.05     0:03
  BAT      01-02    9:10    0.06     0:04
```

The column time_diff is time difference between two observations by using code:
`df['time_diff']=df['time'].shift(-1)-df['time']`

I want to calculate the time-weighted spread for **each stock in each day**, but I got problem in deleting/excluding the last observation in each stock-day. i.e. I want to delete/exclude those observations

```
 stock     date     time   spread  time_diff 
  VOD      01-01    11:04   0.02    22:00 
  BAT      01-01    13:05   0.04    10:02
  ...       ...     ...     ....     ...
```

because their time difference include the next day's variable.

The question here is how to delete/exclude the last observations for each stock-day in `pandas` or `dask` dataframe. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First group by on columns to get 'per stock per day' data. Then, use tail with negative indexing to exclude last row.

```
df = df.groupby(['stock','date']).apply(lambda x: x.tail(-1))
```

Comment: This looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55907156/4819376) answer and doesn't seem to work.

Comment: hi @Aarsh Trivedi. Thanks for this. I got a warning     UserWarning: `meta` is not specified, inferred from partial data. Please provide `meta` if the result is unexpected.
  Before: .apply(func)
  After:  .apply(func, meta={'x': 'f8', 'y': 'f8'}) for dataframe result
  or:     .apply(func, meta=('x', 'f8'))            for series result

Comment: I think its because the dataset is dask dataframe instead of pandas dataframe.

Comment: hi @rpanai, the answer does works to me as negative indexing has been implemented in pandas in recent versions.

Comment: @FlyUFalcon, are you able to get desired output besides the warning?

Comment: No. I think its because I am use Dask instead of Pandas dataframe. Dask has wired groupby function.

Comment: @AarshTrivedi It doesn't work for me neither in `pandas` or `dask` do you mind to create a reproducible example?