# group by filtered pandas dataframe and select latest in each group

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm facing a problem with filtered dataframe and groupby

Say I have this dataframe

```
    id     product   date
0   220    6647     2015-09-01 
1   220    6647     2014-09-03 
2   220    6647     2014-10-16
3   826    3380     2014-11-11
4   826    3380     2015-12-09
5   826    3380     2015-05-19
6   901    4555     2015-09-01
7   901    4555     2014-10-05
8   901    4555     2014-11-01
```

I'd like to first select rows of year 2015 and then groupby id and get the latest by date

I've read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525911/group-by-pandas-dataframe-and-select-latest-in-each-group/41525937#41525937?newreg=50c3a8a53d0144f5a902a8a4166a0bf0), that works great on the entire df
but it seems it's not working if I first try to filter the df like this

```
my_date = datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 31)
df = df[df.date>my_date]
```

now if I run the following code

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id').date.idxmax()]
```

it gives my the following error

> attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence

Any help would be appreciated :)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `df = df[date>my_date]` you have only `date`, not `df.date`, so that's probably causing the error.

This code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime

txt = '''id     product   date
220    6647     2015-09-01
220    6647     2014-09-03
220    6647     2014-10-16
826    3380     2014-11-11
826    3380     2015-12-09
826    3380     2015-05-19
901    4555     2015-09-01
901    4555     2014-10-05
901    4555     2014-11-01'''

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(txt))
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) # convert date to datetime

my_date = datetime(2014, 12, 31)
df = df[df.date>my_date]

print(df.loc[df.groupby('id').date.idxmax()])
```

Prints:

```
    id  product       date
0  220     6647 2015-09-01
4  826     3380 2015-12-09
6  901     4555 2015-09-01
```

Comment: thanks but that is not the problem... simply I forgot to type df before date

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it
the example I posted is taken from another article and it works perfect
my own example is a bit different
my dataframe groupby item is taype category
if I leave it as object it works