# Python: sum values in column where condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['exchange'] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
df['type'] = ['deposit', 'deposit', 'trade', 'deposit', 'deposit']
df['value'] = [10, 10, '30', '40', '100']
```

which looks like:

```
    exchange     type       value
 0  1            deposit    10
 1  1            deposit    10
 2  1            trade      30
 3  2            deposit    40
 4  3            deposit    100
```

I want to add the elements in the `"value"` column where `"type"='deposit'` based on the `"exchange"` and forward-fill to get something like this:

```
    exchange     type       value   balance
 0  1            deposit    10      10
 1  1            deposit    10      20
 2  1            trade      30      20
 3  2            deposit    40      40
 4  3            deposit    100     100
```

where `"balance"` is the sum of `deposits` filtered by `"exchange"`.

Is there a way to do this pythonically without for loops/if statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first group by "exchange", then apply `np.cumsum` and finally assign the result where `type` is "deposit".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.loc[df["type"]=="deposit", "balance"] = df.loc[df["type"]=="deposit"].groupby("exchange", sort=False)["value"].apply(np.cumsum)
```

Finally you can fill missing value with the forward-fill as you have mentioned.

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `groupby` + `cumsum` to fill in "balance" column; this fills in for "trade"s as well, so you `mask` the result depending on with `type` is "deposit" or not and forward fill using `ffill` if it's not "deposit":

```
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(int)
df['balance'] = df['value'].mask(df['type']!='deposit').groupby(df['exchange']).cumsum().ffill()
```

Output:

```
   exchange     type  value  balance
0         1  deposit     10     10.0
1         1  deposit     10     20.0
2         1    trade     30     20.0
3         2  deposit     40     40.0
4         3  deposit    100    100.0
```

Comment: @ALollz I see; so we need to `mask` it before `groupby` right? Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You use `where` to `NaN` non deposit rows and then use an `expanding` `sum`, within each exhange group as it considers `NaN` 0 when summing so it winds up forward filling just as you want.

```
df['balance'] = (df['value'].where(df['type'].eq('deposit'))
                   .groupby(df['exchange'])
                   .expanding().sum()
                   .reset_index(0, drop=True))

   exchange     type  value  balance
0         1  deposit     10     10.0
1         1  deposit     10     20.0
2         1    trade     30     20.0
3         2  deposit     40     40.0
4         3  deposit    100    100.0
```

Comment: I think both your and @enke solutions work only if "exchange" is sorted. In my solution I added `sort=False` in the `groupby`,

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco No it will work regardless. `groupby` maintains the order of rows within the group, the `sort` only determines whether the keys you group by are sorted in the end, it has nothing to do with individual rows. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185894/iteration-order-with-pandas-groupby-on-a-pre-sorted-dataframe/52557580#52557580

Comment: I think this is the most syntactically correct answer

Comment: @ALollz yes sorry I was wrong. I have tried with a not-sorted "exchange" and it works fine.